# Single word for a person who hates sitting idle

Tags: single-word-requests

What do you call a person who hates siting idle?

Comment: Before submitting a question, please do some research then explain why this didn't tell you what you wanted to know. Even a basic Google query will throw up some suggestions and ideas.

Comment: **Never** consult a thesaurus when writing your résumé, especially not our local elugameosaurus here.

Answer (score 2):

You could try the word:

[**Restless**](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/restless)

> unwilling or unable to stay still or to be quiet and calm

You could also consider Antonyms of [Idle](https://www.thesaurus.com/browse/idle) such as '*Active*' or [Lazy](https://www.thesaurus.com/browse/lazy) such as '*Energetic*' or '*Lively*'

Answer (score 1):

**What do you call a person who hates siting idle?**

Try this answer, hope it works for you

**Industrious**

> adjective: UK: ​An industrious person works hard:[Link C.E.D.](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/industrious?q=Industrious)